# Use result object of first concordion call as arg in secound concordion call

Tags: java, concordion

I want to use the variable person.id in order to do an other call. But it seems like concordion does not support this ("Invalid expression"). Am I obliged to  use a bean with person and job and do a call like getLoginAndJob ?

```
<span c:execute="#person = login(#login,#password)"></span>
<span c:execute="#job = getJob(#person.id)"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep specifications simple and maintainable, Concordion deliberately restricts the expression format that is allowed when instrumenting specifications.

In this case, I'd suggest changing the getJob() method in the fixture class to take a person object.

However, if you do want to remove the restriction you can apply the annotation @FullOGNL to your fixture class and Concordion will then accept any expressions that the OGNL library allows, including this one.

Since this question comes up fairly often, I've added it to the [Concordion FAQ](http://concordion.org/Questions.html#complexExpressions).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to assign the value you need into a variable. So your code would become:

```
<span c:execute="#person = login(#login,#password)"></span>
<span c:set="#personId = getId(#person)"></span>
<span c:execute="#job = getJob(#personId)"></span>
```

If your Person class doesn't yet have a getter method for its id field, you would have to add it.